# Passing Input Text From text_field_tag as a variable for a URL...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Okay, so I didn't know really how to word this correctly, but here is essentially what I am trying to do.
I am trying to take the text that a user inputs into my search box and pass it on to the URL.
Here is my view page so far:

```
<h1>What's the weather like by you?</h1>
<br />

<%= form_tag('http://api.wunderground.com/api/myAPIkey/conditions/q/**USER_TEXT_FROM_TEXT_FIELD_TAG**.json',:method =>
'get') do %>

<p>
    <%= text_field_tag 'zipcode', params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Check It Out!", :name => nil %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

I know this is probably such an easy thing to do, but I can't seem to find any way to correctly do it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript that will observe the field change and update the URL when it changes. Have you considered that?

Comment: @Beerlington Could you provide a little code sample on how to do that please? I understand what you're saying, just not %100 sure on how to implement it... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to redirect form submission to different url based on user input.

My no **JavaScript** sugestion would be to go through your own controller and redirect_to custom url. Something like this:

change your view to:

```
<h1>What's the weather like by you?</h1>
<br />

<%= form_tag('/weather') do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag 'zipcode' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Check It Out!", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

create weather controller:

```
rails g controller weather create
```

add this line to your config/route.rb file:

```
match 'weather' => 'weather#create', via: :post
```

and modify you app/controllers/weather_controller.rb to look like this:

```
class WeatherController < ApplicationController
  def create
    redirect_to "http://api.wunderground.com/api/myAPIkey/conditions/q/#{params[:zipcode].split.join('+')}.json"
  end
end
```

This isn't a nice solution and it isn't the smartest solution, it simply duplicates your code using rails stack. Your question doesn't give many information about what you would like to to with the date returned by api?? Do you really want to simply redirect to given url and see data as json?

I just try to give you another idea how to tackle this problem, its not a final solution.

Comment: And I am planning on parsing the data after the re-direct, which I hope I can figure out, and then making a nice looking page which displays the parsed weather data.

Comment: you can't parse it after redirect, you have to do it before redirect. simple steps would involve fetching data from given url and save it in instance variable **then** redirect_to show action and then nicely format it in a view. check [rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) for a great examples.

Comment: I just stumbled upon that issue after bashing my head on the keyboard for an hour, haha. Thanks again, man, I really appreciate the extra effort in your answer!